# Why do we have to assign a value while using while loop, in case of asking user to enter more values?

Tags: c++

I saw a C++ program in my C.S. book whose source code is:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
  char choice=‘y’; //why is this required?
  int marks, classx, test;
 
  while (choice=='y'||choice==‘Y') {
    cout<<"Enter marks:";
    cin>>marks;
    cout<<"\nEnter class:";
    cin>>classx;
    cout<<"\nWant to Enter more? (y/n)";
    cin>>choice; //Can't understand why **choice** is assigned **'y'** before while loop?
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In this code, I can't understand why have we assigned the character `'y'` before `while` loop. I've omitted the value of `choice` which assigns `'y'` in the line 5, but after that it doesn't runs, even without showing any error!

Please explain me why have we assigned `'y'` to character **`choice`** before `while` loop.

> Please note that I am a newbie to the programming world, and started
>   off with C++

Comment: If you didn't assign it to y before the loop in this case then it would never enter the loop the first time it would fail immediately and your program would do nothing

Comment: I suggest starting off with one of the fine books listed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: In C++, you have to declare variables before you use them unlike in some other languages (Matlab and Visual Basic to name a few).  Additionally, you want to unconditionally enter the while-loop at least once to run the input code.  If `choice` was left uninitialized, the while-loop may not actually execute because the conditional statement may not be true.  You could also remove the `choice` initialization and use a `d{}while()` loop instead.

Answer (score 3):

Because the very beginning condition for the while loop is if `choice=='y'`, if at the very beginning choice doesn't equal 'y' then it will never even enter the loop to begin with.

If you really don't want to initialize `choice` first, then change your while loop to a do~while instead:

```
do
{
     cout<<"Enter marks:";
     cin>>marks;
         cout<<"\nEnter class:";
      cin>>classx;
          cout<<"\nWant to Enter more? (y/n)";
      cin>>choice; //Can't understand why **choice** is assigned **'y'** before while loop?

} while (choice=='y'||choice==‘Y');
```

In this case, the `do` starts a loop with no condition, your first loop will always happen.  At the very end of the loop, it only loops again if the `while` condition is true.

Comment: Yeah, I know about the do-while loop and even compfortable with it! But, I just strucked up in this while.

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise `choice` will have a garbage value that may not equals to either `'y'`  or `'Y'` and your loop condition at first time becomes false. If you initialized with `y` then first time loop will execute for sure (initialized `choice` with `'y'` or `'Y'` means code behavior is well defined = always executes for first time).

If you wants to user to enter choice for first time then add extra `cin` before loop.

```
// here you may leave choice uninitialized, know behavior is defined 
cout<< "\nWant to Enter more? (y/n)";
cin>> choice; 
while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y'){
     cout<< "Enter marks:";
     cin>> marks;
     cout<< "\nEnter class:";
     cin>> classx;

     cout<< "\nWant to Enter more? (y/n)";
     cin>> choice; 
}
```

**Remember:** Garbage  value derives undefined behavior.
Additionally, its always do practice to initialize a variable in your code with default value.

Comment: But why have we only used 'y' (i.e., the condition value of while looop) as the initial value for "choice"?

Comment: @SubhadeepDey because in `||` logical or operator is any value is true then condition became true. You can also initialized with `'Y'` your code will run equally well.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey What other initial value would you suggest?  If you pick a value other than 'y' or 'Y', then the while check will fail and you will not enter the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It's required here *only* because of how the `while` loop is constructed.

Note the loop conditionals:

```
while (choice=='y'||choice==‘Y')
```

If `choice` is not set to `y` or `Y` before the `while` is executed the first time, the condition will never be satisfied, and the loop will never begin.

Try it yourself under a debugger and you will see.

Comment: thanks! please rate my question as it annoys me each time while I see my ratings in -ve. It is very difficult for a newbie to tolerate with. I hope you understand what I am saying?

Comment: @SubhadeepDey: I find it somewhat ironic that you're asking me to upvote your question, but you haven't accepted an answer yet.  Don't you?

Answer (score 1):

The value is assigned in the beginning because only then it will enter the loop or else the condition

```
while (choice=='y'||choice==‘Y')
```

fails. So the choice variable is initialised

Comment: then, the user must enter the value before the loop too!

Comment: We provide a provision for the user to go on adding values once he has entered one value, which happens when he enters the loop. But prompting the user to input a value(virtually asking him to continue even before he has started) is meaningless

Comment: thanks! please rate my question as it annoys me each time while I see my ratings in -ve. It is very difficult for a newbie to tolerate with. I hope you understand what I am saying?

Answer (score 1):

`choice = 'y'` make sure that the code in the `while` loop is done **at least 1 time**. Else, the loop may be executed once or may not be executed at all, depending on platform/compiler.

Also, using a debugger will help you answer some questions more rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

You asked

> But why have we only used 'y' (i.e., the condition value of while
>   looop) as the initial value for "choice"?

The while loop `while (choice=='y'||choice==‘Y')` specifies 2 conditions with the || (logical OR operator) between them. That means, that whichever condition is true, the while loop executes.

We needed to set choice to an initial value, to be sure that the loop executes the first time. That initial value could have been either 'Y' or 'y', any of them would have allowed the while loop to run the first time.

Comment: thanks! btw, can u please rate my question as it annoys me each time while I see my ratings in -ve. It is very difficult for a newbie to tolerate with. I hope you understand what I am saying?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't assign it a value, it will have an indeterminate value, and the `while(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y')` will see a value that is not `y` or `Y`, and thus not enter the loop the first time, not allowing the user to enter anything.

By the way, you're mixing backquote (`) and single quote (') in your code, the compiler will not accept that. Use only single quote.

Comment: This has been typed by mistake. BTW, I dont know how to write backquote! :P

Comment: Backquote is the button to the left of the `1` key on most keyboards.  Single quote is the key to the left of `Enter` on most keyboards.

Comment: Obviously, where those keys are depends on what keyboard layout you have - different countries/languages have them in different places - and yes, it makes a big difference in programming.

Answer (score 0):

In this program the the While loop fist check the value of 'choice' then the code get executed so it should be initialize first by 'y' or 'Y' to execute the code first time